# How to filter dataframe in order to get one occurrence per day at specific time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My dataset has a datetime column that has one entry for every hour of the day for many days.
For example:

```
123412,2020-03-26 12:00,
123412,2020-03-27 12:00,
123412,2020-03-27 09:00,
123412,2020-03-27 09:00,
123412,2020-03-27 15:00,
123412,2020-03-26 15:00,
123412,2020-03-27 11:00,
123412,2020-03-27 12:00,
```

The example is not ordered, but as I said, there is one entry for every hour of the day.

The way is I want to filter this data is, for example, take datetime `2020-03-26 12:00`.
Then, the filter will return the following rows:

- 2020-03-26 12:00
- 2020-03-25 12:00
- 2020-03-24 12:00

and etc.

I've tried the `Grouper` like this `df2 = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(key=DATETIME, freq='D'))` but that didn't work.

How can I accomplish this? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter datetimes by times by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`Series.dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
print (df)
        a                date   b
0  123412 2020-03-26 12:00:00 NaN
1  123412 2020-03-27 12:00:00 NaN
2  123412 2020-03-27 09:00:00 NaN
3  123412 2020-03-27 09:00:00 NaN
4  123412 2020-03-27 15:00:00 NaN
5  123412 2020-03-26 15:00:00 NaN
6  123412 2020-03-27 11:00:00 NaN
7  123412 2020-03-27 12:00:00 NaN

d = '2020-03-26 12:00'

df = df[df['date'].dt.time.eq(pd.Timestamp(d).time())]
print (df)
        a                date   b
0  123412 2020-03-26 12:00:00 NaN
1  123412 2020-03-27 12:00:00 NaN
7  123412 2020-03-27 12:00:00 NaN
```

If want only unique datetimes:

```
d = '2020-03-26 12:00'

df = df.drop_duplicates('date')
df = df[df['date'].dt.time.eq(pd.Timestamp(d).time())]
print (df)
        a                date   b
0  123412 2020-03-26 12:00:00 NaN
1  123412 2020-03-27 12:00:00 NaN
```